# Transparent modal backdrop

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a modal backdrop completely transparent (specifically for one modal) and I'm having a difficult time achieving this. From the docs it says I can apply a custom class with backdropClass. When I open my modal, I call:

```
backdropClass: 'transparent-backdrop'
```

But no matter what styling I put in this class (whether to achieve transparency or just change the backdrop color), the backdrop does not change. My CSS looks like this:

```
.transparent-backdrop {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

I can modify the backdrop color using windowClass (and the 'in' class):

```
windowClass: 'my-window-class'

.my-window-class.in {
   background-color: #000;
}
```

However, if I try to set the opacity in a similar way:

```
.my-window-class.in {
   opacity: 0;
}
```

my backdrop is still present, but now my modal disappears. Can anyone tell me the correct way to modify the opacity of the backdrop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

`.transparent-backdrop.in {
  opacity: 0;
}`

Here's a screenshot showing the transparent backdrop in Chrome
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for the edit (only just noticed it). And you are right. My problem is arising because I'm loading a modal on top of a modal. I want the first modal to have a backdrop, but the second modal that gets loaded on top of the first to have the transparent one. This is possible with bootstrap but doesn't work with angular-ui. It seems there is a single .modal-backdrop element in angular-ui as opposed to one for every modal. I guess I need to create a backdrop for each modal without using the built in modal-backdrop.

Comment: Sounds like you have a pretty clear idea how to solve your problem now. Good luck.